# What are square brackets used for in JavaCC

Tags: java, recursion, compiler-construction, javacc

guys in JavaCC when I have a non-terminal inside square brackets, for example:

```
void NonTerminal: {}
{
    [OtherNonTerminal()]
}

void OtherNonTerminal: {}
{
    <TOKEN> [<OTHERTOKEN> OtherNonTerminal()]
}
```

What do the square brackets around it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[OtherNonTerminal()]` is the same as `(OtherNonTerminal())?` and means that `OtherNonTerminal` is optional. That is, `NonTerminal` can either match `OtherNonTerminal` or nothing.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! So, even if i had under the NonTermianl() production rule, `OtherNonTerminal | {}`, its the same?

Comment: @webchatowner Yes.

Comment: So is `[ NonTerminal() OtherNonTerminal()]` the same as `NonTerminal() OtherNonTerminal | {}`? Just making sure. @sepp2k

Comment: @webchatowner Yes or just `NonTerminal() OtherTerminal() |` - an alternative can be empty, you don't need the `{}`.

Comment: @webchatowner No, it's not wrong, the empty braces just don't do anything.

Comment: The empty braces do make a convenient place-holder for Java code that you might add later.